# Problem with currency conversion in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

In my store I try to convert currencies, for English-speaking users to $, for Russian-speaking users in rubles. But there is a problem that the conversion does not work when changing the language.

At **layout.blade** i use:

```
const LANG = '{{ Config::get('languages')[App::getLocale()] }}';
```

too see what language user now use, and it show's `en`, okay, all good.

At item price i use:

```
@if(Lang::has('antaras8.kurs')) {{ round($item->price) }}  @else{{ \App\Http\Controllers\Controller::getActualCurs($item->price) }} @endif
```

At /resources/lang/ru and /en i has file antaras8.php with some translations. At **ru** lang i has antaras8.kurs and it use only `{{ round($item->price) }}`, but in **en** lang i has only file antaras8 without `kurs` and it need to use `\App\Http\Controllers\Controller::getActualCurs($item->price) }}` how i write, but it always show Russian currency without changes, but language set to english.

Why is it? How i can fix this problem?

**EDIT**

/lang/ru/antaras8.php:

```
<?php

return [
    'info1' => 'от',
    'info2' => 'до',
    'kurs' => 'руб'
];
```

/lang/en/antaras8.php:

```
<?php

return [
    'info1' => 'from',
    'info2' => 'to'
];
```

It's my antaras8.php file with translate. At RU version i has `kurs` at EN version i don't has this value.

Comment: Can you output something else to check that the first condition isn't passing?

Comment: if i use EN or RU site version, i always received currency in Rubles, i think `@if(Lang::has('antaras8.kurs'))` this condition doesn't work, but i has language file `antaras8.kurs` only for RU

Comment: Test that like so `@if(Lang::has('antaras8.kurs')) Russian  @else English @endif` and let me know what you're getting

Comment: Sorry, at first did not understand what was required of me :P always i received Russian, but i also switched from RU to EN version site, and received Russian

Comment: Then the check is passing while it shouldn't, edit the question and include the relative parts of your language files

Comment: @SalimDjerbouh i edit question and add **antaras8** translate file